# Haskell -- List Comprehension with Lists inside a Tuple inside a List

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, list-comprehension

I have:

```
type Person     = String
type Book       = String
type Database   = [(Person,[Book])]
```

I'm trying to define a function:

```
books :: Database -> Person -> [Book]
```

that takes in 
1) a list of tuples (which contain a string and a list of strings
2) a String name

and returns a list of strings (namely the books from the database)

I want to use list comprehension, but I don't know how to access elements within a list that is in the tuple inside of the database list.

Thoughts?

Example database would look like:

```
db = [("Bob", ["Red Riding Hood", "Alice in Wonderland"]), ("Carol", ["Game of Thrones"])]
```

And if I ask for say "Carol", it should return ["Game of Thrones"].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have an association list you can use the [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3alookup) function. It pretty much works exactly like you want:

```
getVal :: Database -> String -> Maybe [String]
getVal  = lookup
```

The only difference is that it returns a `Maybe` but IMHO that is the right behavior, consider what would happen if you didn't have a value in your database when you looked it up?

Since you want to use pattern matching here is the source of `lookup`

```
lookup                  :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
lookup _key []          =  Nothing
lookup  key ((x,y):xys)
    | key == x          =  Just y
    | otherwise         =  lookup key xys
```

Or in your case

```
getVal :: Database -> String -> [String] --Avoids a Maybe if you want
getVal _key []          =  []
getVal  key ((x,y):xys)
    | key == x          =  y
    | otherwise         =  getVal key xys
```

Comment: Okay I see how that works, but is there anyway for me to do this using a list comprehension or pattern matching?

Answer (score 2):

As the other posters said, `lookup` is the way to go here: it's the standard procedure to search for something in an association list.

That said, a solution using a list comprehension **would be**

```
books :: Database -> Person -> [Book]
books db authorName = [book | (author, bookName) <- db,
                              author == authorName
                              book <- bookName]
```

It's taking out `(author, bookName)` tuples one by one, discarding the ones where the author doesn't match. If then adds the books of that author to the result.

Again, this implements a sort-of workaround for a function that's already in the standard libraries, and it's less readable in general. Really, use `lookup`.

Comment: Yeah that seemed to be the better way to go at it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a list comprehension for implementing that function - list comprehensions are better suited for building lists.

What you are looking for is the Prelude function [lookup](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3alookup):

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

As you can see it almost has the correct type, if `a ~ Person` and `b ~ [Book]` and after swapping the arguments. Since you want `[Book]` back and not `Maybe [Book]` you can wrap the whole thing inside [fromMaybe](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html#v%3afromMaybe), resulting in:

```
books db = fromMaybe [] . flip lookup db
```